# Send an email when a boolean is true

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to send an email whenever a boolean value equals.  The email needs to contain info from a list that is created in a groovy script earlier in the job.  whenever this list isn't empty I will need to create a text/HTML email with the contents of the list.

currently I have the email extension plugin but I can't find a way to integrate it with what I need.  Is there anyway I could send the email using groovy or use a plugin that triggers based on what I need?

Comment: could you provide your code and mark where you want to send an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who it may concern, I discovered that with the Flexible Publish Plug in you can add conditionals to your post build actions, easiest to use string values and just compare those. this is because you can set up parameters at the start of your build that you plan to use to store info in the build environment, and it can be accessed from other places.

you can set string params using the following code:

```
def paramTempHolder = new StringParameterValue('PARAM', 'desired value')
build.replaceAction(new ParametersAction(paramTempHolder))
```

for me I used `send` to indcate I needed to send my email so my code read:

```
def paramTempHolder = new StringParameterValue('SendEmail', 'send')
```

I then used `$SendMail` as string 1 in flexible publish and just `send` as string 2.  If the condition is meet it will send my email.  I can use the same parameter manipulation to get the info I need into my email so that it sends like I want it to.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that inorder to use the replaceAction method you will need to add the following import to your script:

```
import hudson.model.*
```